# java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android

12-27 16:57:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(22081): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mygps.android.AlarmReceiver.

This is one of my error in logcat. What is the error and how can i solve it.

sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private int currentIntervalChoice = 0;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setAppInfo();
        addButtonListeners();
        enableControls();
    }

        private void addButtonListeners() {
                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.start_logging)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }

        private void setAppInfo() {
                TextView txtInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.app_info);

        txtInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.app_info)));

        Linkify.addLinks(txtInfo, Linkify.ALL);
        }

        private void toggleLogging(boolean isStart, int interval){
                AlarmManager manager =   (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent loggerIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

            if(isStart){
                    manager.cancel(loggerIntent);

                    AppSettings.setServiceRunning(this, false);

                    AppLog.logString("Service Stopped.");
            }
            else{
                    setLogFileName();

                    long duration = interval * 60 * 1000;

                    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), duration, loggerIntent);

                    AppSettings.setServiceRunning(this, true);

                    AppLog.logString("Service Started with interval " + interval + ", Logfile name: " + AppSettings.getLogFileName(this));
            }
    }

    private void enableControls(){
            boolean isServiceRunning = AppSettings.getServiceRunning(this);
            String buttonText = getString(R.string.start_logging);

            if(isServiceRunning){
                    buttonText = getString(R.string.stop_logging);

                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval)).setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval)).setEnabled(true);
            }

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.start_logging)).setText(buttonText);
    }

    private void changeLoggingIntercal(){
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final String loggingIntervals[] = { "5 minutes", "15 minutes", "30 minutes", "1 hour" }; 

    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.logging_interval));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(loggingIntervals, currentIntervalChoice, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            currentIntervalChoice = which;

                            setLoggingInterval(currentIntervalChoice);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });

    builder.show();
    }

    private void setLoggingInterval(int intervalChoice){
            int interval = 5;

            switch(intervalChoice){
                    case 0:         interval = 5;   break;
                    case 1:         interval = 15;  break;
                    case 2:         interval = 30;  break;
                    case 3:         interval = 60;  break;
                    default:        interval = 5;   break;
            }

            AppSettings.setLoggingInterval(this, interval);
    }

    public void setLogFileName(){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String dateString = sdf.format(new Date());
            String filename = "GPSLog." + dateString + ".kml";

            AppSettings.setLogFileName(this, filename);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId())
                    {
                            case R.id.start_logging:{
                                    toggleLogging(AppSettings.getServiceRunning(MainActivity.this), 
                                                              AppSettings.getLoggingInterval(MainActivity.this));

                                    enableControls();       

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.logging_interval:{
                                    changeLoggingIntercal();

                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    };
```

}

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip">


    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/app_info"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/start_logging"
            android:text="@string/start_logging"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/logging_interval"
            android:text="@string/logging_interval"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

logfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dip">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter log filename here." />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you posted the correct code. What's the line which causes the error ?

Comment: There's no casting in your code, I suggest you to look at the line where the error is suppose to be and to give us that given code (maybe in the subfunctions enableControls() or changeLoggingIntercal(). You must have some bad casting somewhere.

Comment: I have edited my code. This is the complete code that i am using. Kindly look into the edited code and tell me where am i going wrong. Also tell me how can i save the GPS Logger value that i get from the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the xml layout file associated with this and the full logcat. My suggestion, altho this may not matter, is to stop using the `((Button)findViewById(R.id.logging_interval))` method of referring to your controls and just use a variable. I only say this because I have seen the error when android interprets this as an attempt to recast and freaks out

Answer (score 0):

add alarm receiver class in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"> 
   <intent-filter> 
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> </intent-filter>   
</receiver>
```

i think problem with your Button's

get button's in onCreate() and then use those button's where you required..

Comment: I have added my xml file. PLease look into the layouts and tell me where am i going wrong.

Comment: change this line Button a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_logging); in onCreate() and use that name in the listeners.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have solved it. I had to change the AlarmReceiver.java class. It works fine now